# Any differences between these resize cursor types in JavaFX on various platforms?

Tags: java, javafx, operating-system

JavaFX provides several convenient built-in cursor types for easy styling. Specifically, they are:

```
[ null | crosshair | default | hand | move | e-resize | h-resize
| ne-resize | nw-resize | n-resize | se-resize | sw-resize | s-resize
| w-resize | v-resize | text | wait ]
```

as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node).

The types are mostly self-explanatory, but I have questions on the many `-resize` cursor types. As far as Windows 10 is concerned, there are actually only four types:

[image: ss2]

`n-resize s-resize v-resize` all designate vertical

`e-resize w-resize h-resize` all designate horizontal

`nw-resize se-resize` both designate upper-right to bottom-left

`ne-resize sw-resize` both designate upper-left to bottom-right

---

So all the types JavaFX provides almost seem redundant. My guess is that on some other platforms, those cursor types actually designate different cursor images. But I am quite unfamiliar with all the various OSes out there.

So my question is, do the JREs for most mainstream OSes do what Windows JRE does and don't care, or is there some platform that actually distinguishes between e.g. `nw-resize` and `se-resize`? Specifically I want to know whether this is the case for the many Linux and Unix-like distributions, including mobile-oriented OSes.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.gnome-look.org/p/999998/

Comment: @xmojmr interesting. So is there any way to designate the two 'bidirectional diagonal resize' cursors in JavaFX assuming a Linux platform that makes such distinctions?

Comment: I don't know, sorry